# What does it mean when 'close(1)' appears in your question instead of just 'close'?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I notice that in one question the close button has a one in parenthesis:

```
link | edit | close(1) | delete | flag
```

Does this mean someone has voted to close the question?  If so, how do I see and respond to their comments and reasons for wanting to close it?

Comment: We all know that this is a typo for close(2), the official name of the linux system call for closing a file descriptor :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that someone has voted to close the question. If it said `close (2)` then two people would have voted and so on.

Given that you can see the link you should click it and see what type of close vote it received. Knowing that you might be able to edit your question to address the issue implied by the close vote.

Of course if the vote is to migrate the question then head over to the target site and make sure you have a linked account ready to receive the question.

Comment: Well I was reluctant to click on close for fear that that would mean I wanted the question closed.  Perhaps the user interface needs to be updated to avoid this miscue?

Comment: @WilliamKF - nothing drastic ever happens on Stack Overflow without confirmation dialogs being presented to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It means that *one* close vote has already been cast on that question.